# How can I get my Python script to work correctly with both normal execution and pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pytest, file-structure

I'm stuck on import issues while using pytest. My file structure looks like:

```
src/
| __init__.py
| main.py
| util.py
tests/
| __init__.py
| test_main.py
tox.ini
```

---

If I want to run main.py with something from util.py normally, I would use the import line:

`from util import UTIL_VALUE`

If I try to test main.py with pytest, though, I get the error:

`ModuleNotFound: No module named 'util'`

---

I am able to get my pytest working by using this alternate import line in main.py:

`from src.util import UTIL_VALUE`

This makes my pytest run fine, but now when I try to run main.py normally, I get:

`ModuleNotFound: No module named 'src.util'`

---

I just want to be able to run the file and while also having it importable with my pytest, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that removing the __init__.py's and adding an empty conftest.py in the src/ folder allowed me to keep the original `from util import UTIL_VALUE`. My working file structure ended up being

```
src/
| conftest.py
| main.py
| util.py
tests/
| test_main.py
tox.ini
```